# Publisher MyTestSource resources could not be found or are not accessible to the EventLog service account (NT SERVICE\EventLog)

Tags: c#, etw, wevtutil

I'm trying register EventSource using Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister from nuget. I rebuild my project and its generates manifest.

[image: Debug]

After that I run cmd by admin and execute this command:

```
wevtutil.exe im "ETW loggiing.MyTestSource.etwManifest.man"
```

Then cmd return this warning

```
**** Warning: Publisher MyTestSource resources could not be found or are not 
accessible
to the EventLog service account (NT SERVICE\EventLog).
```

After that I changed file permission

[image: permission]

It works, but why this warning occured and how can I fix that with code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by setting access to dll file from code:

```
FileInfo fInfo = new FileInfo(path);
        if (fInfo.Exists)
        {
            FileSecurity security = fInfo.GetAccessControl();
            security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null), FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, AccessControlType.Allow));
            fInfo.SetAccessControl(security);
        }
```

Comment: Is there a way to fix it in Command or `.bat` file instead of C#?